# How do we get the desired inequality?

Tags: matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

We have that $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is invertible and $||A||\leq \frac{1}{\theta}$, where $\theta>0$.

I want to show that it holds that $||A^{-1}x||\geq \theta||x||$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I have done the following:

We have that $$||I||=||A^{-1}A||\leq ||A^{-1}||\cdot ||A||\leq ||A^{-1}||\cdot \frac{1}{\theta}\Rightarrow 1\leq ||A^{-1}||\cdot \frac{1}{\theta} \Rightarrow ||A^{-1}||\geq \theta$$

So, we get $$||A^{-1}x||\leq ||A^{-1}||\cdot ||x||$$ with $||A^{-1}||\cdot ||x||\geq \theta\cdot ||x||$

Is everything correct so far? How do we get the desired inequality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x \in \mathbb R^n$. Since $A$ is invertible, we have $x=Ay$ for some $y \in \mathbb R^n$. Then $y=A^{-1}x$ and

$||x||=||Ay|| \le ||A|| ||y|| \le \frac{1}{\theta}||y||=\frac{1}{\theta}||A^{-1}x||$.

Comment: Ah I see!! Thank you very much!! :-)